# Why do I always get Recall=0, Precision=0 in Class 1 only in Fold1 during 5-fold validation?

Tags: classification, python, cross-validation, unbalanced-classes

I implement a classifier in python based on Negative Selection (Artificial Immune Systems) that classifies a dataset of transactions as either fraud (Class 1) or non-fraud (Class 0).
The dataset is highly imbalanced so I use 5-Fold stratified cross validation and undersampling in the training data.
For some reason I always get Recall=0, Precision=0 in Class 1 of Fold1, no matter how many times I run the script with different parameters. I get really good results on Folds 2,3,4,5. Does anyone know why is this happening only in Fold 1?

Example Output:

```
Details of Fold 1 Test Set:
Number of samples in Fold 1 Test Set: 3084
Class 0 samples in Fold 1: 2900
Class 1 samples in Fold 1: 184

Fold 1
Train Set Size Before Undersampling: 12336
Train Set Size After Undersampling: 1478
Test Set Size: 3084
Number of detectors generated: 737
Class 0: Precision = 0.9403
Class 0: Recall = 1.0000
Class 1: Precision = 0.0000
Class 1: Recall = 0.0000
AUPRC on Test Set: 0.5298
***********************************
UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no predicted samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, msg_start, len(result))

Details of Fold 2 Test Set:
Number of samples in Fold 2 Test Set: 3084
Class 0 samples in Fold 2: 2900
Class 1 samples in Fold 2: 184

Fold 2
Train Set Size Before Undersampling: 12336
Train Set Size After Undersampling: 1478
Test Set Size: 3084
Number of detectors generated: 1475
Class 0: Precision = 0.9986
Class 0: Recall = 1.0000
Class 1: Precision = 1.0000
Class 1: Recall = 0.9783
AUPRC on Test Set: 0.9898
***********************************

Details of Fold 3 Test Set:
Number of samples in Fold 3 Test Set: 3084
Class 0 samples in Fold 3: 2899
Class 1 samples in Fold 3: 185

Fold 3
Train Set Size Before Undersampling: 12336
Train Set Size After Undersampling: 1476
Test Set Size: 3084
Number of detectors generated: 2213
Class 0: Precision = 1.0000
Class 0: Recall = 1.0000
Class 1: Precision = 1.0000
Class 1: Recall = 1.0000
AUPRC on Test Set: 1.0000
***********************************

Details of Fold 4 Test Set:
Number of samples in Fold 4 Test Set: 3084
Class 0 samples in Fold 4: 2899
Class 1 samples in Fold 4: 185

Fold 4
Train Set Size Before Undersampling: 12336
Train Set Size After Undersampling: 1476
Test Set Size: 3084
Number of detectors generated: 2951
Class 0: Precision = 1.0000
Class 0: Recall = 1.0000
Class 1: Precision = 1.0000
Class 1: Recall = 1.0000
AUPRC on Test Set: 1.0000
***********************************

Details of Fold 5 Test Set:
Number of samples in Fold 5 Test Set: 3084
Class 0 samples in Fold 5: 2899
Class 1 samples in Fold 5: 185

Fold 5
Train Set Size Before Undersampling: 12336
Train Set Size After Undersampling: 1476
Test Set Size: 3084
Number of detectors generated: 3689
Class 0: Precision = 1.0000
Class 0: Recall = 1.0000
Class 1: Precision = 1.0000
Class 1: Recall = 1.0000
AUPRC on Test Set: 1.0000
***********************************

Summary after Cross-Validation:
Number of clusters: 1476 

Threshold: 1
Average number of detectors generated: 2213.00
Overall performance metrics averaged over folds:
   - Precision: 0.8000
   - Recall: 0.7957
   - AUPRC: 0.9039

Total runtime: 2 min, 53 sec
```

I tried simple 5-fold cross validation and I get the same bad results in Fold 1.

Comment: About that oversampling, you may find [this thread interesting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/1352).